# Making strings in a list into only a string in the list

Tags: python

how do i add up all the strings together in a list into a big string?
For example:

```
alist = ["Hi","How are YOU","THANK YOU"]
```

How do i make it into:

```
alist = ["Hi,How are YOU, THANK YOU"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.join` method.

**Ex:**

```
print([", ".join( ["Hi","How are YOU","THANK YOU"])])
```

**[More Info](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join)**

Answer (score 1):

Use join()

```
alist = [', '.join(alist)]
```

Example

```
alist = ["Hi","How are YOU","THANK YOU"]
alist = [', '.join(alist)]
print(alist)
```

Output

```
['Hi, How are YOU, THANK YOU']
```